# floating point conversions and performance

Tags: c++, c, performance, floating-point

I am aware of the errors that can occur when doing conversions between floating point numbers and integers, but what about performance (please disregard the accuracy issues)?

Does performance, in general, suffer if I do n-ary operations on operands of differing arithmetic types, that is, on differing floating point types (e.g. `float` and `double`) and floating point/integer type combinations (e.g. `float` and `int`)? Do there exist rules of thumb, such as, to keep all operands the same type?

P.S.: I am asking because I'm writing an expression template library and would like to know whether to allow binary operations on vectors containing values of differing arithmetic types.

Comment: Yes, there are costs to converting between different types. I might give an in-depth answer if nobody else does by the time I get back from my midterm.

Comment: Since floating-point operations are non-trivial in terms of base-2 arithmetic, compilers often emit helper functions (see why libgcc is needed?) and that can seriously affect performance.

Comment: The thing is, your program does **not** do n-ary operations on operands of differing types. It promotes the arguments according to e.g. C99's 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions, and then the n-ary operation takes place, typically with arguments of the same type (there are a few exceptions but none that involve floating-point types).

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: I'm aware of these implicit conversions, that's why I ask about performance. There may be costs involved in causing them, even though everything compiles and works fine.

Comment: @user1095108: The worst cost I would be aware of is transferring from integral to floating point register in the CPU. If you go back and forth about it, especially. But unless it's in a very tight loop, the bottleneck is more likely to be CPU <-> RAM transfers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the answer to this question is going to vary by target architecture, because the conversions can (but might not) to occur in hardware.  For example, consider the following code, which causes some interconversions between int and float:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int precoarced = 35;
    // precoarced gets forced to float
    float result = 0.5 + precoarced;

    // and now we force it back to int
    return (int)result;

    // I wonder what the disassembly looks like in different environments?
}
```

When I tried to compile this with g++ (I'm on Ubuntu, x86) with default settings, and used gdb to disassemble:

```
   0x00000000004004b4 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000004004b5 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004004b8 <+4>: mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004bb <+7>: mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004bf <+11>:    movl   $0x23,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004c6 <+18>:    cvtsi2sdl -0x8(%rbp),%xmm0
   0x00000000004004cb <+23>:    movsd  0x10d(%rip),%xmm1        # 0x4005e0
   0x00000000004004d3 <+31>:    addsd  %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x00000000004004d7 <+35>:    unpcklpd %xmm0,%xmm0
   0x00000000004004db <+39>:    cvtpd2ps %xmm0,%xmm0
   0x00000000004004df <+43>:    movss  %xmm0,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004e4 <+48>:    movss  -0x4(%rbp),%xmm0
   0x00000000004004e9 <+53>:    cvttss2si %xmm0,%eax
   0x00000000004004ed <+57>:    pop    %rbp
   0x00000000004004ee <+58>:    retq
```

Note the instructions with a cvt-prefixed mnemonic.  These are conversion instructions.  So in this case, the conversion is happening in hardware in a handful of instructions.  So, depending on how many cycles these instructions cost, it could be reasonably fast.  But again, a different architecture (or different compiler) could change the story.

Edit: On a fun side note, there's an extra conversion in there due to me accidentally specifying 0.5 instead of 0.5f.  That's why the cvtpd2ps op is in there.

Edit: x86 has had FP support for a long time (since the 80s), so C++ compilers targeting x86 will generally make use of the hardware (unless the compiler is seriously behind the times).  Thanks Hot Licks for pointing this out.

Comment: the compiler could have been smart enough to have done the conversion at compile time, but it wasnt...

Comment: @user1095108 Indeed.  This doesn't surprise me too much though; I was at default settings, for one.  Having the float as a literal like that is not a typical 'practical' use case.  Also, compiler implementors are probably scared of any float-related optimizations since they have to be *very* careful.  For example, you might think commutativity of addition (A+B=B+A) would be a valid basis for float addition optimizations, but due to fp imprecision it is not;  it can horribly break the precision of some FP algorithms.

Comment: Note that the conversion instructions have been there, in one form or another, since the original 8087 coprocessor.  So virtually all systems with floating-point hardware will have the conversions in hardware.

Comment: @Hot Licks That's a good point; any modern x86 machine, paired with an even half-decent compiler, should be utilizing the hardware.  I must admit I'm curious how the picture looks like on non-x86 architectures, especially in embedded applications?  I would guess if the architecture has FP support at all, it would also provide conversion functionality (or be a *pure* FP architecture), but perhaps there's some exceptions?

Comment: I know that the IBM Power architecture has full hardware floating point embedded, and I'm *nearly* certain that includes the conversions.

Answer (score 2):

On most machines, conversions between float and int formats is fairly fast, being assisted by features of the floating-point hardware.

However, one should, of course, make some effort to express literals in the "correct" format, if only for documentation purposes.  And it doesn't hurt to use explicit casts as well, for documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Usually there are some performance penalties, although negligible compared to other things. This is due to data migration between integral and floating-point registers, and other possible ABI issues.

The answer for such questions is much always the same. In doubt? *Benchmark it.* Performance is hardly theoretically predictable.

Comment: don't forget, that I've asked about rules of thumb. I am aware of the bench rule.