# Why is the return type of the "ceil()" function "double" instead of some integer type?

Tags: c, types, type-conversion, integer, double

I've just implemented a line of code, where two numbers need to be divided and the result needs to be rounded up to the next integer number. I started very naïvely:

```
i_quotient = ceil(a/b);
```

As the numbers `a` and `b` are both integer numbers, this did not work: the division gets executed as an integer division, which is rounding down by default, so I need to force the division to be a floating point operation:

```
i_quotient = ceil((double) a / b);
```

Now this seems to work, but it leaves a warning saying that I am trying to assign a double to an integer, and indeed, following the header file "math.h" the return type of the `ceil()` function is "double", and now I'm lost: what's the sense of a rounding function to return a double? Can anybody enlighten me about this?

Comment: How would you specify `ceil` if the argument were too large to be represented by an integer type? E.g. `1E500`?

Comment: Why don't you do `i_quotient = (a + b - 1) / b;`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A double has a range that can be greater than any integer type.
Returning `double` is the only way to ensure that the result type has a range that can handle all possible input.

Comment: Let apart an implementation _can_ provide integers with more bits than `double` can represent, `double` likely has less precision than `long long`.

Comment: @Olaf: even on those vanishingly rare implementations where an integer type has more bits than *double* can represent, infinite values are still out of range for integer types.

Comment: @chqrlie: You should concentrate on the second half of my comment. on all architectures with 64 bit `double` (x86/x86/ARM, etc.), `long long` has always more significant bits. For LP64 (e.g. POSIX 64) this also applies to `long`. I did not say they can represent the same range, nor it is a good idea not to use `double`.

Comment: @Olaf: OK your wording was a tad confusing, a *double* can represent values larger than 64 bits, but with a potential loss in precision.  This is all a moot point. `ceil()` returning a `double` is defined for all values of the `double` type. If it returned an integer type, the result would be incorrect in many cases.

Comment: @chqrlie: "... double likely has less precision than long long" sounds pretty clear. I never wrote about range. The first half refers to the fact that there is no upper limit on the width of the integer types. But I agree this is a more esoteric option.

Answer (score 4):

`ceil()` takes a `double` as an argument. So, if it were to return an integer, what *integer type* would you choose that can still represent its ceiled value?
Whatever may be the type, it should be able to represent all possible double values.

The integer type that can hold the highest possible value is `uintmax_t`.
But that doesn't guarantee it can hold all *double* values even in some implementations it can.

So, it makes sense to return a `double` value for `ceil()`. If an integer value is needed, then the caller can always cast it to the desired integer type.

Answer (score 3):

OP starts with two integers `a,b` and questions why a function `double ceil(double)` that takes a `double`, does not return some integer type.

Most floating-point math functions take floating point arguments and return the same type.

A  big reason `double ceil(double)` does not return an integer type is because that limited functionality is rarely needed.  Integer types have (or almost always have) a more limited range that `double`.  `ceil(DBL_MAX)` is not expected to fit in an integer type.

---

There is little need to use `double` math to solve an integer problem.

If code needs to divide integers and round up the quotient, use the following.  Ref:[@mch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806391/why-is-the-return-type-of-the-ceil-function-double-instead-of-some-integer#comment70800495_41806391)

```
i_quotient = (a + b - 1) / b;
```

The above will handle most of OP's cases when `a >= 0` and `b > 0`.  Other considerations are needed when `a` or `b` are negative or if `a + b - 1` may overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Because why should it? Converting betwen int and double takes time. This overhead can become significant. If you want to convert a double to int do so explicitly:

```
i_quotient = (int)ceil((double) a / b);
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668348/how-expensive-is-it-to-convert-between-int-and-double) if you want to know more about this latency. You have to consider that C is quit old and achievable performance was one of the top priorities. But even C# and other modern languages usually return a floating value for ceil just for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving technical discussions apart, couldn't be simply for consistency?

If the function takes a double it should return a result of the same type, if there's no particular reasons to return a different type.
It's up to the user to transform it to an integer if he needs to.
After all you may be working only with doubles in your application.

Although `ceil` means to round up to the next whole number , it doesn't mean strictly that it is an integer, it's obvious that an integer is a whole number but that doesn't have to prejudice our mind.